# The use of "la"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, archaicisms

I have read many a novel set in the Regency period where *la* is used in conversations.

> La, Susan, don't be so bothersome

What is its purpose and correct use?

Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 5):

You are referring to the use of **[la](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/la)** as an exclamation.  According to M-W:

> - *interjection 
>     chiefly dialect*
>     —used for emphasis or expressing surprise

Interjection
 **[la](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/la)** (from Wiktionary)

> - (obsolete) Used to introduce a statement with emphatic or intensive effect.
>     (archaic) Expressing surprise, anger. etc.
>
>   - 1811, Jane Austen, Sense and Sensibility, vol. III ch. 2:
>       “Oh, la! here come the Richardsons. I had a vast deal more to say to you, but I must not stay away from them any longer.”

Etymology: 
from French *la*, Italian *la*.

Comment: It is used extensively in Malaysia and Singapore. e.g. Parent to child: 'Would you go to the shop please'; Child: 'Cannot la! Too much homework!'.

Comment: This is interesting!! Are you sure it is the same interjection used in 19th century novels, or is it  an expression of local origin?

Comment: It's not archaic. It's used pervasively in Southeast Asian English as well as among some Asian neighbourhoods in Australia. The origins of "meh" is also of southeast asian and hong kong English.

Comment: @Josh61 I'm not sure about the origin of much of the pidgin in South East Asia. I think it is unlikely that 'la' derives from the French, but perhaps from some Malay or Chinese interjection. My wife, who is a Cantonese speaking Malaysian, thinks it is from Malay. Apparently it is not used by Cantonese speakers in Hong Kong.

Comment: A look at just two English Dictionaries shows the interjection "la" of the Regency Period (cf OP) to come straight from Middle English from Old English.

Comment: @WS2 The interjection used in Chinese-influenced areas is indeed from Chinese, from 啦 _la_. This is a sentence-final particle, and it is so in English, too. The _la_ used in Jane Austin novels is a different word altogether: it is almost always used at the _beginning_ of a clause and is ultimately from what in Modern French is _là_ (and means more or less the same thing, too).

Comment: @BlessedGeek: In the West it is _highly_ archaic.

Comment: In Italian, "la" means "the" (fem, sing.). "Là" either means "there" or... [eng] "la". I'm sure someone also uses "There" as an interjection in English, which would be consistent. Unfortunately I can't edit just a letter so you get a comment instead.